# Canvas Add arrow keys controls to screen for ipad and other devices

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In a canvas, an object is moved according to the arrow keys of keyboard. But I want to add arrow keys controls in screen so, that user can move that object with mouse or with touch in ipad or from smart phone devices.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4hvn/5818mgL4/)

All i want to do is, trigger keyboard events on the mousedown according to the direction buttons.

```
$('#down').click(function(e)
{
    //?????
});
```

Html

```
<div class="keys" id="down">Down</div>
<div class="keys" id="up">Up</div>
<div class="keys" id="left">Left</div>
<div class="keys" id="right">Right</div>
```

Javascript

```
function update() {

    // check the keys and do the movement.
    if (keys[38]) {
        if (velY > -speed) {
            velY--;
        }
    }

    if (keys[40]) {
        if (velY < speed) {
            velY++;
        }
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        if (velX < speed) {
            velX++;
        }
    }
    if (keys[37]) {
        if (velX > -speed) {
            velX--;
        }
    }

    // apply some friction to y velocity.
    velY *= friction;
    y += velY;

    // apply some friction to x velocity.
    velX *= friction;
    x += velX;

    // bounds checking
    if (x >= 295) {
        x = 295;
    } else if (x <= 5) {
        x = 5;
    }

    if (y > 295) {
        y = 295;
    } else if (y <= 5) {
        y = 5;
    }

    // do the drawing
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();

    setTimeout(update, 10);
}

update();

// key events
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

How do i trigger keyboard event from the mousedown or touch event.

Comment: This should help you out mate http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/

Comment: Nice little sim that :) Think maybe using touches on the canvas, looking at where the event is relative to the ball to decide on the direction of movement would make a nice initiative touch. Also means less listeners to resister!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a long procedure, of adding multiple events, but its very simple.

```
function upTrue(){keys[38] = true;}
function upFalse(){keys[38] = false;}

var upKey = document.getElementById('up');
upKey.addEventListener('mousedown', upTrue);
upKey.addEventListener('touchstart', upTrue);
upKey.addEventListener('mouseup', upFalse);
upKey.addEventListener('touchend', upFalse);
```

Throughly you can add events for other three directions

Comment: Moving the touch out of the button bounds will mean the cancel event won't fire. Use one cancel event attached to the whole doc.

Comment: `document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
  var i=keys.length;
  while(i--)keys[i] = false;
 }, false)`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do this when you can use the [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events)? you have more than touch event there, you have some event like move finger, touch the screen and more